# mysql sequential updates or simultaneous updates

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask, whether it is more optimum to perform a simultaneous update in 3 mysql tables using a joined query or perform each in turn sequentially?  Thanks
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EV

Answer (score 1):

From a purely performance point of view the less connection you made to the database, the better, if the total execution time of the joined query is not bigger that the sum of time for the 3 query, which should be the case.

So, without more informations, I'll say the joined query will performs better.

But I think the best answer is "**Try it**". Write some code to run a thousand time each query and then do a comparison of the times.

Comment: Thanks for your response Krtek

Comment: @Nick you should accept the correct answers to your questions. I'm not talking especially about this one, but also these you asked in the past. (There's a check mark under the votes of every answer to accept it). People answer more often to people which accept and votes for good answers.